# On mouseover event remove class from list-item'child

Tags: angularjs, class, mouseover

```
<md-list layout-padding>
     <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="obj in value" ng-mouseover="ctrl.toggleTextTruncateClass(this)">
           <div class="md-list-item-text">
                <h3 class="text_truncate">{{obj.goalName}}</h3>
                <h4>{{obj.goalDescription}}</h4>
                <h4>{{obj.goalAchievementCount}} Achievement(s)</h4>
            </div>

            <md-divider></md-divider>
    </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```

I want when hover of md-list-item I want to remove class text_truncate from h3 inside list item text

I tried with

```js
self.toggleTextTruncateClass = function (element) {
               angular.element(document.querySelector('.md-3-line')).find('h3').toggleClass('text_truncate')
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

Just use `ng-class` to toggle the class.

```
<h3 ng-class="{'text_truncate': hovered}">{{obj.goalName}}</h3>
```

Then switch `hovered` variable in `<md-list-item>`:

```
<md-list-item ng-mouseenter="hovered=true" ng-mouseleave="hovered=false" ng-repeat="obj in value" class="md-3-line">
```

Comment: Shouldn't ng-class="{'text_truncate': hovered}" be ng-class="{'text_truncate': hover}" ?

Answer (score 0):

try using `ng-mouseenter` and `ng-mouseleave` combined with `ng-class`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseenter
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngMouseleave
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

```
<md-list layout-padding>
  <md-list-item class="md-3-line" ng-repeat="obj in value"  ng-mouseenter="hover = true" ng-mouseleave="hover = false">
    <div class="md-list-item-text">
      <h3 ng-class="{text_truncate: hover}" class="text_truncate">{{obj.goalName}}</h3>
      <h4>{{obj.goalDescription}}</h4>
      <h4>{{obj.goalAchievementCount}} Achievement(s)</h4>
    </div>

    <md-divider></md-divider>
  </md-list-item>
</md-list>
```